# Sorting Algorithm that minimizes the maximum number of comparisons in which individual items are involved

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm interested in finding a comparison sorting algorithm that minimizes the number of times each single element is compared with others during the run of the algorithm.

For a randomly sorted list, I'm interested in two distributions: the number of comparisons that are needed to sort a list (this is the traditional criterion) and the number of comparisons in which each single element of the list is involved.

Among the algorithms that have a good performance in terms of the number of comparisons, say achieving O(n log(n)) on average, I would like to find out the one for which, on average, the number of times a single element is compared with others is minimized.

I supposed that the theoretical minimum is O(log(n)) which is obtained by dividing the above figure on the total number of comparisons by n.

I'm also interested in the case where data are likely to be already ordered to some extent.

Is perhaps a simulation the best way to go about finding an answer?

(My previous question has been put on hold - This is now a very clear question, if you can't understand it then please explain why)

Comment: The Programmers stackexchange is probably a better place for this question, see: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @rpy: by average I mean the expected number for a list of length n, assuming all initial orders are equally likely. for a concrete example, you may want to think about having an algorithm that feeds the comparisons but real persons that make those comparisons (e.g. between pictures/ideas); in that case the objective is making the comparison as less tedious as possible.

Comment: @nibarius when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat that's a good point, thanks for pointing that out. I should probably have mentioned that future posts like this should probably go to Programmers since you can't migrate posts yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you definitely should do simulations.
There you will implicitely set the size and pre-ordering constraints in a way that may allow more specific statements than the general question you rose.

There *can*, however, not be a clear answer to such question in general.

Big-O deals with asymptotic behaviour while your question 
seem to target smaller problem sizes. So Big-O could hint on the best candidates for sufficiently large input sets to a sort run. (But, e.g. if you are interested in size<=5 the results may be completely different!)
For getting proper estimate on comparison operations you would need
to analyze each individual algorithm.

At the end, the result (for a given algorithm) will necesarily be specific to the dataset being sorted.

Also, `on avarage` is not well defined in your context. I'd assume you intend to refer to the number of comparisions on the participating objects for a given sort and not avarage over a (sufficiently large) set of sort runs.

Even within a single algorithm the distribution of comparisions an individual object is taking place in may show a large standard deviation in one case and be (nearly) equally distributed in another case.

As complexity of a sorting algorithm is determined by the total number of comparisons (and position changes thereof), I do not assume there will be much from therotical analysis contributing to an answer.

Maybe you can add some background on what would make an answer to your question "interesting" in a practical sense?